# HAPROXY configuration for DSR

Tags: tcp, load-balancer, haproxy

I have to do load balancing in TCP mode using HAproxy. The backend application needs to use the client source IP. The only solution I found over the internet is configuring haproxy in DSR mode. I found the following link
https://www.haproxy.com/blog/layer-4-load-balancing-direct-server-return-mode/ it only explains the Linux server configuration, not haproxy configuration and it's nowhere else. If someone can help me on haproxy configuration for DSR mode it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible solutions for your request.

`http-request set-src src`
https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20set-src

When the destination server supports the **Proxy protocol** the can you use `send-proxy` https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#5.2-send-proxy

Comment: Backend application is not a web application.  Backend application will only accept TCP traffic. Hence we cannot use both of the methods which u have suggested

Comment: are you sure that the beckend server does not support the proxy protocol?

Comment: Yes we tried that option..

Comment: hm okay. Maybe you can ask this on the haproxy mailing list.